# Changing folder name, with current being a '\n'

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive

Some time ago I've had a Mac with a HDD filled with bad sectors. While I had backed up most stuff, I needed an up-to-date iPhoto Library, which was unfortunately broken - on export, iPhoto crashed, just as Python scripts for extraction did. So I've booted Ubuntu from USB drive, plugged in one more external HDD and copied over the entire iPhoto Library folder with this quite stupid command:

```
cp -r "$HOME/Pictures/iPhoto Library/" "/Volumes/Toshiba/
> "
```

In other words, everything was copied into a new folder, whose name is '\n'. Mac OS doesn't even notice that folder, neither does Ubuntu. Windows "sees" that folder, but can't rename, open or do anything with it.

My question is, how can I rename this folder to be usable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename it using `$'\n'`:

```
mv $'\n' "iPhoto Library"
```

(Assuming that this folder had, in fact, just `\n` there)

What does `ls -la /Volumes/Toshiba` show?

In my case (OS X 10.8.4) it shows the newline character as "`?`", so if you have just "`?`" there, you can use the command above to rename it (don't forget to `cd /Volumes/Toshiba`).

If there's some text in there, like "iPhoto Library?", then you can rename it with an `mv "iPhoto Library"$'\n' "iPhoto Library"`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't answered accurate enough at first; I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, it shows `?`, renamed successfully. Thanks! :)